# Flash AS3 suddenly unable to delete values from objects

Tags: actionscript-3, flash, object

This is fairly interesting. Flash CS6 has suddenly lost the ability to iterate through objects and delete their values (which did work before)

Delete all values from object keys

```
for each(var key:String in ScoreKeep.scoreCard)
    ScoreKeep.scoreCard[key] = 0;
```

The object (ScoreKeep.as)

```
static public var scoreCard:Object = { 

    "Fish":6, "Golfball":2, "Gloves":8, "Boot":4, 
};
```

You can trace the object key. The value will still be there.

Comment: Yes that's a wrong iteration which could in no way have worked before ("it did work before" : nope it didn't cos it couldn't). Thats'a wrong question and a wrong statement. The "key" in that iteration is actually the value not the key so it correctly set all values as key to 0.

Comment: It did actually wipe out the values up until now. For two months. Not sure how. But the only reason I asked the question was because it had stopped working due to some other change, maybe the debug or flash version publish settings. Either way, quite a critical distinction. And much thanks.

Comment: That question is unclear eh? You need questions spoon fed to you with all the life sucked out of them? Can't be bothered to infer, use intuition, deduce, any of that, eh. I can't stand all this fake pretentious formality. As if what we do is SO important. You're closed as unclear.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are using it wrongly, it is not supposed to be `for each` but `for`. `for each` would take the value, not the key.

You also have a "`,`" after the last prop in your object, I assume that's a typo (and should result in a compile-time error).

Comment: As usual, a disgusting syntax trifle. I just want to be done with this game so I can never use Flash again. Thanks for the correct answer, though. Not often you find that here.